# How can I try Android developers Bluetooth Sample described in the guide?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that uses Bluetooth but I can't run the threads examples in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices.
The main Activity I created works but I need to connect two or more devices and I want to know how to start the threads and how to call the private classes. Can you please help me? I hope I've been clear, I'm sorry for my english. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) application in the API Samples

It handles the connection of two devices, sending data to each other

Comment: I'm using this example and I solved my previous problem. Now I can scan and view as list all the devices, but I still can't connect my device to an another one. Can I post the code (an Activity and a Service class) of my app here?

Comment: it would be better to open a new specific question =)